# Managing package.lisp/defpackage in emacs

Tags: emacs, common-lisp, package, slime

My current project is growing larger and beginning to span multiple packages. Export and import management is waxing burdensome. My buffer list is filling up with: package.lisp, package.lisp<2>, package.lisp<3>, etc. These are very hard to distinguish when switching buffers with `C-x b`.

Every time I add a function to a package and wish to export it, the aggravation of hunting down the correct file nearly drives me to HN. I've considered using [cl-annot](https://github.com/m2ym/cl-annot)'s @export thing, but it feels like going over to the dark side.

Is there a nice way to manage defpackages in emacs? Perhaps a way to jump from the current source file to the relevant defpackage?

Comment: FWIW recent Emacsen (IIRC, starting with Emacs-24.1) should use "<DIR>" instead of "<N>" for the buffer names, where DIR will hopefully give you a better idea of which is which.

Comment: You know, you can also put several package definitions into a single file.  You can also use "one package per file" style where you define the package at the start of each file.

Answer (score 1):

If you use slime, "C-c x" will export the symbol at point.

Comment: Aha! And edits the package import list. Cool! Is there anything similar for adding imports to the defpackage?